# Sunspot search in production Ruby on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, solr, sunspot

I install solr-tomcat on my production server, and start this, replace my conf/schema.xml & conf/solrconfig.xml from application but it does no work.

In the :8080/solr/admin/ i have HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration.

What I do wrong and how I install sunspot on my production server correct, on my development works fine.

This is my sunspot.yml

`production:
  solr:
    hostname: myhost
    port: 8080 #tomcat defaults to port 8080
    path: '/solr' # or '/solr' (ubuntu 12.04)
    log_level: WARNING
    pid_dir: '/var/run'`

Comment: I just use jetty on production: http://kingstonlabs.co.uk/blog/how-to-install-solr-36-on-ubuntu-1204/

Answer (score 0):

I installed it exactly the way shown in [this awesome Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot). Made some changes in Tokenizers and Filters in `schema.xml` and works like a charm in production. Did not find any need to install solr separately.